# Where is the init method invoked in enum classes?

Tags: python, enums, init

I have a class like the one below.

```py
from enum import Enum, unique
from typing import Tuple

@unique
class Test(Enum):
    v1: Tuple = (1, "value_1")
    v2: Tuple = (2, "value_2")

    def __init__(self, value_number: int, value_name: str) -> None:
        self.value_number = value_number
        self.value_name = value_name

    @classmethod
    def get_value_name_by_value_number(cls, number: int) -> str:
        for member in cls.__members__.values():
            if member.value_number == number:
                return member.value_name
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = Test.get_value_name_by_value_number(number=2)
    print(name)
```

When I run the code, the output is correct. But I don't understand why it's working with no problem. As far as I know the `__init__` method is called on the creation of an instance. The method I'm calling is `classmethod` and thus I'm not creating an object and calling it directly from the class. So the `__init__` is not invoked. But how does my class know what `member.value_number` and `member.value_name` are?

Comment: This is all handled by the metaclass: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0194bbbee6a12264e93d3217c774e226f0a1737d/Lib/enum.py#L272 so it happens during class creation. `enum` relies heavily on metaclass magic

Comment: The elements (`v1` and `v2`) are themselves `Test` instances, and will have `__init__` invoked.

Comment: Side note: your `NotImplementedError` should problably be a `ValueError` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the `Test` class, the `Enum` internals will create all enum members and [manually call your `__init__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Lib/enum.py#L298):

```
enum_member.__init__(*args)
```

You'd think it'd just instantiate your class normally somewhere, but with how much weird magic goes on in the `Enum` implementation, it turns out that wouldn't work.